# Upgrading SSD on 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I'm about to buy a 15" Macbook Pro with 512 GB SSD. Does anyone know if it is possible to upgrade the SSD after I have bought it?

Comment: OWC sell them - http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/ I've no idea what it would do to your warranty.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Are you sure OWC sells them for the 2015 MBP?  From what I see I'd say no.

Comment: @Tetsujin.  That one is incompatible.  The highest model that OWC supports is MacbookPro10,1 which is the MBP 2013 model.  The 2015 MBP is identified as MacBookPro11,4

Comment: ah, OK - I couldn't figure out what the machine number was - the ad just said 09 - 'current' guess they need to revise their estimate of 'current'

Comment: @Tetsujin, one of the best information resources I found for Apple-branded products is [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca).  It goes way back and is kept current too, if you allow the app to update itself.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible?

Yes.

The question is can you get a drive to upgrade to?

Apple uses a "proprietary PCIe 2.0 x4" interface for their storage.  There are SSDs out there that match the specs (like this [Samsung on Amazon](http://amzn.to/1MiazVA)), but for some reason they are not compatible

So, bottom line....

Yes, you can upgrade it, but only with a genuine Apple SSD (at this point).  Your best bet is to get the most you can afford now because there is zero cost savings plus the added headache of disassembly/reassembly.  IMO, it just isn't worth it.