# MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.7 13" Early 2015 upgrade factory SSD with Intel 600p?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade

I researched this all over and it appears that the Intel 600p is the correct form factor/spec SSD, but I can't find any references to anybody using it to upgrade one of these MBPs.  The only drives I can find people linking to are the [OWC Aura drives](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-air/2013-2014-2015), which I've had heat issues with (on another laptop), and had 3 Aura drives fail that I had to RMA.  So, I'm trying not to use OWC.

The only other [topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195200/upgrading-ssd-on-2015-macbook-pro) on this site about this upgrade is pretty outdated and before the Intel 600p was available, so I'm trying to find recent info...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that both MCE and Transcend make drives to upgrade MacBook Pro/Air with PCIe SSDs. Here are links to the options, which are cheaper than OWC:

MCE - http://store.mcetech.com/mm/merchant.mvc?
Transcend - https://us.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrive/

Comment: Looks like the MCE drives are a bit cheaper than the Aura drives.  The Transcend JetDrive unfortunately only supports up to 2013 MBPs.  I wish there was a cheaper option, like the Intel 600p, since that's so much cheaper!  Thanks.

Comment: Although, since MCE charges $89 for the enclosure for your old drive, OWC's prices are a tiny bit cheaper, or almost equivalent if you look at their "Drive Only" prices...   But, I've had SO many issues with the OWC Aura drives that I'm hesitant to save a couple bucks.  ;)